# Is there an example of two topologically different knots with the exact same Conway notation?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

on whether a Conway notation describes a unique knot, so it'd be two knots which are fundamentally topologically different

Comment: Please provide some information, background , what has been attempted

Comment: though i'm not really trying to solve a problem, more of trying to know the factual answer to a direct factual question, its also more of a yes/no question, "yes, there is such an example", or, "no, no such example exists, it is impossible"

Comment: The Conway notation is intended to be used as a way of identifying a knot, more or less like giving an ID to each knot.

Comment: thanks @WhatsUp, so, sorry, is the answer to the question "yes" or "no"?

Comment: Should be "no", two knots are the same if and only if they have the same Conway notation.

Comment: @Whatsup I came across this example of two different ways of writing a Conway notation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400960/unique-conway-notation-for-knots

though regardless, in order to answer the question, i think that we'd have to know that each Conway notation only has one possible knot, aka, "if two knots have the same Conway notation, they are the same knot"

Comment: @jimjim or, if this was a problem which i was trying to solve, it'd be like trying to prove a major theorem on my own without any external info

Answer (score 1):

Let's specify that two (unoriented) knots $K$ and $K'$ in $S^3$ are topologically "the same" iff there is a homeomorphism between $(S^3,K)$ and $(S^3,K')$ that preserves the orientation of $S^3$.

Conway notation is designed as a way to describe an (unoriented) prime knot.  Prime knots generally have very many Conway notations that describe them.  A particular Conway notation describes just a single prime knot.  If two prime knots each can be described by the same Conway notation, then they are topologically the same.

The reason for this is that Conway notation gives a textual description of how to construct a knot diagram.

One problem with the notation is that it requires having on hand a catalog of all the basic polyhedra, with their names, vertex orders, and vertex orientations. This catalog is somewhat arbitrarily constructed, and it depends on everyone agreeing on a convention for Conway notation to be decodable. You could say that you're trading needing to have a full knot table for needing to have a table of only the alternating knots with no twists -- there are many *many* fewer of these.

(What fails for Conway notation for non-prime knots is that if a diagram is obviously not prime, then the basic polyhedron you get after reducing all the algebraic tangles is not in the standard list -- you're meant to describe each connect summand separately, I suppose.  For the connect sum to be well-defined, you need to also somehow record orientations of each knot, and I'm not sure if Conway notation has any convention for this.)